# Can a div with z-index applied be floated?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a layout where the navigation sits in a div on top of an image. Im using z-index to do this. I tried making the image a background image but I couldnt get it to scale properly when changing the size of the browser window.

The z-index seems to be working properly but now my div that would contain the nav no longer floats right.

Anyway to fix this?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
    }
    #container{
        width: 100%;
        height: 1000px;
        background-color: yellow;
        position: relative;
    }
    #blue{
        margin-top: 20%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 10%;
        background-color: blue;
        float: right;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    #test_image{
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="container">
        <img id="test_image" src="http://i1370.photobucket.com/albums/ag265/arsinek1/web_development/test_zpsfbvzo3ij.jpg">
        <div id="blue"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Position:fixed with a float doesn't make sense.

Comment: Indeed - the question seems to be built on the flawed assumption that z-index is the issue rather than absolute positioning (including fixed positioning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you use `position:fixed;` instead of `float:right;` use:

```
right: 0;
```

To make your **image responsive** the easiest way is to set it do the desired element as a **background-image** using:

```
background: url(yourBGimage.jpg) 50% / cover;
```

Not sure why you use overly the `fixed` but here's just an example to reflect the above lines (and without the z-index stuff): ***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/puruki/2/edit)***

Comment: Thanks. The right:0 seems to do the trick. I also changed the fixed to absolute. Ill try your background example and see how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

For the background as an image approach did you tried?

```
background-size: cover;
```